# Audio DSP for hobbyists

Tags: dsp

I'm not experienced with DSP. The few texts I've cracked open pre-suppose a level of sophistication i'm not at yet. Is there some stepping stone to start dabbling or is DSP all or nothing?

Comment: I _love_ the book http://www.dspguide.com/ which is freely available for download. A long time ago, it taught me basically everything I needed to know about DSP, long before I started at a university and knew any relevant maths. That book and any programming language will get you started. Because I was poor but had access to free printing, I even printed out the whole thing and I still use it as a reference 15 years later.

Comment: I also recommend reading the dspguide.cim book. Very good beginner resource on DSP.

Comment: I found this one as the best beginner. Try this - Digital Signal Processing for Scientists and Engineers.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can start DSP with C, Matlab, or Octave to name just a few. DSP is mainly about filtering, but also about signal processing and algorithms to  manipulate sampled signals in the time and frequency domain. A beginner could learn how to implement filters and also spectral estimation. There are also algorithms to detect\generate tones and chords which might be of interest for audio hobbyists. All you need is some sampled data to play with and a way to manipulate that data, the rest is learning about the math (google is your friend).

Real time DSP involves making these processes run fast in an FPGA or DSP processor, which you would need hardware for. I had some labs once where we built adaptive IIR filters that would filter out a tone real time from audio with only a few msecs of delay. We implemented and tested the filters in C and Matlab before implementing them in hardware.

Comment: DSP is about much, much more than filtering.

Comment: Yes, but I try and answer the question to the context of the questioner. I didn't want to rant on for 15 paragraphs

Answer (score 1):

For $60, you can buy a  "[DM330011-MPLAB Starter Kit for dsPIC DSC](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/DM330011/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMudZehw8RjeZZymMX2Yo%252bGP)" which combines a dsPIC (essentially a PIC24 with added DSP instructions) with a codec..

[image]

It is described as:

> "This Starter Kit introduces users to the dsPIC Digital Signal
>   Controller device using its speech and audio processing capabilities.
>   The kit is USB-powered, has on-board debug circuitry and 24-bit codec
>   for high-quality audio applications."

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Uuuups - did not notice the question date :(

You can start with any Cortex M4 or M7 micro controllers with the DSP instruction set.

For example stm32F4xx stmF7xx or stm32h7.

ARM has quite nice CMSIS DSP libraries as well https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/tree/develop/CMSIS/DSP

As a starting point I would recommend any STM DISCOVERY board as they have microphones & audio amplifiers on board.

$50 (but with the 4" TFT on board and a lots of internal and external memory)
https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32f746gdiscovery.html
[image]

or cheaper $25
https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html
[image]

Comment: "Uuuups - did not notice the question date" - up-to-date answers are always a good idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

ADI ADAU1761 has dual A-D and D-A. with very little DSP knowledge I used it to design and build a mic mixer, controlled by software (i write software). The eval kit is $200. Sigma studio software is easy to learn. tie blocks together like a schematic. EVAL-ADAU1761. I think Audio is a good start. You can generate sine, triangle, square waves manipulate and see on scope or hear on earphones. I am still learning the science under the routines.